# Capture BlueStacks http/https traffic

Tags: fiddler, bluestacks

I'm tring to capture [`BlueStacks`](http://www.bluestacks.com/) http/https traffic but I can't get it working. For example, if I open google.com in Firefox inside BlueStacks, those requests aren't show on Fiddler. I followed strictly those [`step-by-step`](http://www.proxycap.com/bluestacks.html) but I can't see anything on Fiddler. How do I fix this?

Here's my ProxyCap settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Certificate, run CMD , ipconfig see your IP (in my case it was 192.168.1.5)  then in BlueStacks native browser go to 192.168.1.5:8888 (replace IP with yours) and click install certificate, but before installing you need to set lock screen PIN, that's a problem. I haven't figured out how to do it